# ListView with custom layout for each row

Tags: java, android, listview, android-layout

I setup a listview with a layout XML for each row:

```
    this.setContentView(R.layout.item_view);

    ListView m_ListView = this.getListView();
    m_ListView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    m_ListView.setItemsCanFocus(false);
    m_ListView.setCacheColorHint(0x00000000);
    mInflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    ArrayList<View> views=new ArrayList<View>();
    e = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_first, null);

    views.add(e);

    r = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_second, null);

    views.add(r);


    mAdapter = new SillyAdapter(views);
    setListAdapter(mAdapter);
```

now for example i have a `TextView` in `item_first` and i want to set it from the code:

```
    TextView name = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    name.setText(m_item.name);
```

but name is always null.any idea why it happen?

Comment: Can you post the code from SillyAdapter? Did you implement getView in the SillyAdapter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do the following changes in your code.

```
TextView name = (TextView)e.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
name.setText(m_item.name);
```

You are getting name as null since you are calling findViewById method from wrong view or might be calling from activity.
since you are inflating as follows

```
 e = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_first, null);
```

you have to call findViewById on inflated view **e**. so that you will get the instance of textview with id **R.id.textView1** contained in xml **R.layout.item_first**

Hope this will help.